# Excel VBA - Import from a file in the same folder with an arbitrary name but a specific number at the end

Tags: vba, excel, import

I want to be able to import data from a file in the same folder, but it doesn't matter what it's called, but the number at the end does. Currently i have

```
Sub Import_Data()

Dim rng As Range
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim FName As String
Dim c1 As Worksheet
Set c1 = Sheets("c")

    FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "_w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00")
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName)

   c1.Range("L2:O6").Value = WB2.Worksheets(3).Range("M2:P6").Value

    c1.Range("L14:O18").Value = WB2.Worksheets(3).Range("M14:P18").Value

WB2.Close

End Sub
```

I want to change the following line from

```
FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "_w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00")
```

To something like

```
FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + *Any Name before the last 2 digits* & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00")
```

So it will basically not look at the name of the sheet but will look at the 2 digits at the end.

The week numbers will always be unique in the folder but the names might be different. E.g

Folder may contain the following files:

```
Worksheet 1 w21
Different Name w22
Alternate w23
```

If we are in w24, i'd like it to import from "Alternate w23"

I hope this makes sense. Thanks

EDIT - Alternative

If this isn't possible, It would also work if the previous weeks file had the same name as the current file. So if the active workbook was called "Workbook w23" Then it would find "Workbook w22" in the same folder. But it would need to be possible to generalise the name of the sheet. So instead of the original suggestion of *Any Name before the last 2 digits* it would be *The same name as the active workbook with 2 different digits at the end*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question right, you just need a wildcard:

`FName = Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00") & ".xlsm")`

Comment: Re-reading after your edit, I think this may not solve your question. If this isn't what you're looking for, please clarify and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is what i'd like, when I do it however it says that it cant find the file *30.xlsx. For some reason it's picking up the Wildcard as an actual value, *

Comment: Debug.Print the full file name out to make sure it matches what you expect? I noticed in your examples it appears the file may be in a directory: \AIMS_Report_w - check to make sure the full path and filename matches what it should be and let me know.

Comment: the AIMS_Report_w part is the name of the file, so this part is what should be replaced by the wildcard (so it can change). It finds the right folder that the files are in but it looks for a file called "*w30.xlsm". I've edited what you sent to be  `FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00") & ".xlsm"`. But the wildcard just isn't working

Comment: Odd, it should work - in the comments above, your file extension changed. Is it the correct file extension you're searching for? If these are likely to change, I would suggest wild-carding that too e.g. "xls*"

Comment: The file will always be macro enabled (xlsm). it will always be FILEPATH\ *something* w(number).xlsm. Everything is perfect apart from the  *something* part which is the wildcard. Could it be something to do with the " ?

Comment: It shouldn't be as it works for me: `Path = "G:\Direct\folder\"`,  `Filename = "*03.xls*"`,  `Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)` .....and the debug output: `G:\Direct\folder\*03.xls*` (it also opens the file).

Comment: If i debug print the file name i get -----------\AIMs\Test\ * w30.xlsm (where ------- is the rest of the path)

Comment: Got it working - It needed to be `FName = Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00") & ".xlsm")`